# How to restore UIInputViewController self.view after dismissing the keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, keyboard, uiinputviewcontroller

I'm developing an application that has an Keyboard extension, At some uses of the Keyboard extension (for example: when I use the switch keyboard button) the extension is going through the **viewDidDisappear** and at this case I know I can clean the keyboard and it's getting deallocated with all it's views and the memory is freed. At other uses (for example: when using the Notes application and pressing the Done/Back button) the extension is going through the **viewWillDisappear** but not through the **viewDidDisappear**, So in this case I'm not cleaning the Keyboard as it's not reaching my cleaning methods and therefore it's not getting deallocated.

At this point I would expect that when I return to the keyboard by going back to the note for example I would receive the previous **UIInputViewController** with the view I already built.

Unfortunately at this point the **isViewLoaded()** method returns **false** and my **UIInputViewController** is going again through the loadView method therefore building again all the views all over again, as a result the application memory grows until at some point I reach the nasty **didReceiveMemoryWarning** method callback.

I would like to restore somehow the view I created for my keyboard in the **UIInputViewController** that was initialized first. Does some one know is it possible and how could this be achieved?

I was looking into the **restorationIdentifier** to accomplish this task, correct me if I'm wrong but this is used with an ordinary **UIViewController** and can't be used with the **UIInputViewController** as not my AppDelegate is responsible to launch it.

### Update

From further research I made, I came to a conclusion that no matter what the operation you commit:

1. Use Done/Back button in the Notes application.
2. Switch to the Messages app and use the keyboard there.
3. Use the “switch keyboard" button

And other scenarios, **the UIInputViewController class always goes through the init method**.

From my understanding of the object oriented programming this mean that whoever calls my keyboard to reaper does it using the constructor and basically creates a new instance of the keyboard. That means that I will never have an available view on first reappearance of the keyboard in any of the behaviors and I always have to build the keyboard view for the new instance and cleanup the old one. **Is this right? or there is a way to presereve the view of the UIInputViewController?**

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're using your own custom application with the keyboard to store its previous instance, there's no way to do this. In everything besides a custom application designed by you, it is beyond your scope